# Data Values not visible in the DevExpress grid

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using DevExpress Winforms for representing my Grid Structure.
What is happening is that i'm using DevExpress in an already developed application.
I am assigning the DataSet table to DataSource in the grid layout view.
I am using XtraGrid and Column Header is in camelcase.
What is happening is that Column Headings are being displayed, it is showing that 30 entries are loaded but nothing is being displayed.  As in no data value is visible.We found the issue field name is case sensitive.
 How do we handle this ?

Any helps/ leads will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are binding the GridControl to a DataSet, have you set the GridControl's DataMember property to a DataTable contained within the DataSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have visible columns and you can see rows with empty cells I'll bet the field names (GridColumn.FieldName) do not match with column names of your DataTable.

The field names have nothing to do with the header captions (GridColumn.Caption) but the caption is automatically determined out of the fieldname if it is not set to another string.

Comment: Thanks ! so noob of me ! :/